# What is a tailwheel aircraft?

Tags: faa-regulations, glider, logging

I just had a lesson in a SGS 2-33A and my CFI logged it as tailwheel time "because it has a tailwheel".  I laughed and said I'm not sure that's how it works.

The center of gravity is in front of the monowheel and SOP is to wheel land it on the monowheel and then go forward onto the skid.  I wouldn't have thought it counted as tailwheel because the CoG is in front of the monowheel, making it dynamically stable.

What is the official definition of a tailwheel aircraft, and is there anything to stop me from logging this time as tailwheel time?

The closest I could find was [PHAK 3-7](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/phak/media/05_phak_ch3.pdf#page=7) "Landing gear with a rear mounted wheel is called conventional landing gear."  But is there anywhere to find the definition in 14 CFR?

Under the PHAK definition, if you mount a vestigial tailwheel on the rear of a tricycle-gear experimental aircraft, it would be considered to have conventional landing gear.  What's more, you would [be able to fly the experimental aircraft solo without a TWE](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.31#:%7E:text=(B)%20An%20experimental,passenger) to build TW time.

Comment: It looks like when nobody is inside the cockpit, it becomes a taildragger because CoG goes behind the monowheel, so it may depend on if you fill in the logbook inside or outside the glider.

Answer (score 8):

Since it's your logbook you can log anything you want.

But if you are logging flight time in accordance with (U.S. ) [14 CFR Part 61.51](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.51(a))  to meet "training" and/or "recent flight experience," as required by [14 CFR Part 61.31(i)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.31(i)) and [14 CFR Part 61.57 (a)(1)(ii)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61#p-61.57(a)(1)(ii)), this applies to tailwheel **airplanes**, not gliders.

Logging flight time in a glider as "tailwheel" time may complicate your logbook and require you to separate out the tailwheel time you logged in a glider with tailwheel time necessary to meet training and recent flight experience requirements under FAR's 61.31 and 61.57 in an airplane.

Tailwheel glider time is not an FAR requirement.

Comment: Thank you. What about for other purposes such as insurance purposes? Are you aware of any authoritative definition of a tailwheel aircraft?

Comment: @Zaz. No, I'm not aware of any authoritative definition of tailwheel aircraft other than its applicability under FAR part 61 relating to "airplanes."

Answer (score -1):

It is wrong because "tailwheel" is only a slang term for conventional gear, and the type of gear is not determined by the existence of a wheel on the tail but rather as you described the center of mass relative to the main gear when in the flight configuration(with pilot and such).

Conventional gear may use a tail skid or ski rather than a tail wheel, and the tricycle gear planes that I fly have a tail skid to protect the frame from excessively nose-high takeoffs and landings but this does not make them conventional gear.